# Css Drop down menu, how to keep menu infront of content

Tags: css

I have created a Css drop down menu but when i hover over a link i can still see the content beneath.

http://ljessett.hndcomputing.net/lewis/

I have tried editing the z-index but that hasnt work any ideas?

Comment: Not the solution, but I recommend running the page through the w3c validator - you have some improperly formed tags in there and if you're going to be using xhtml strict, it's always a good idea to clean up your markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` will work but it only works on positioned elements. So you need to position your dropdown menus either by declaring the `position` property to be either `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative`. In this case I'd suggest going for `relative`.

Further reading on `z-index`: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: In short: stick `position: relative` on `#navcontainer`. Also: http://w3fools.com/